# How to use Early Stopping for monitoring loss in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Being new to DL and Tensorflow, I am trying to refer to https://machinetalk.org/2019/03/29/neural-machine-translation-with-attention-mechanism/?unapproved=67&moderation-hash=ea8e5dcb97c8236f68291788fbd746a7#comment-67 for implementing a Sequence to Sequence Model with Attention. However, I am quite confused as to how I can implement early stopping to avoid overfitting as the convention `model.fit()` is not being used in the code I am following.

```
if MODE == 'train':
    for e in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        en_initial_states = encoder.init_states(BATCH_SIZE)
        encoder.save_weights(
            'checkpoints_luong/encoder/encoder_{}.h5'.format(e + 1))
        decoder.save_weights(
            'checkpoints_luong/decoder/decoder_{}.h5'.format(e + 1))
        for batch, (source_seq, target_seq_in, target_seq_out) in enumerate(dataset.take(-1)):
            loss = train_step(source_seq, target_seq_in,
                              target_seq_out, en_initial_states)

            if batch % 100 == 0:
                print('Epoch {} Batch {} Loss {:.4f}'.format(
                    e + 1, batch, loss.numpy()))

        try:
            predict()

        except Exception:
            continue
```

Below is the Syntax for `train_step()` function:-

```
@tf.function
def train_step(source_seq, target_seq_in, target_seq_out, en_initial_states):
    loss = 0
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        en_outputs = encoder(source_seq, en_initial_states)
        en_states = en_outputs[1:]
        de_state_h, de_state_c = en_states

        # We need to create a loop to iterate through the target sequences
        for i in range(target_seq_out.shape[1]):
            # Input to the decoder must have shape of (batch_size, length)
            # so we need to expand one dimension
            decoder_in = tf.expand_dims(target_seq_in[:, i], 1)
            logit, de_state_h, de_state_c, _ = decoder(
                decoder_in, (de_state_h, de_state_c), en_outputs[0])

            # The loss is now accumulated through the whole batch
            loss += loss_func(target_seq_out[:, i], logit)

    variables = encoder.trainable_variables + decoder.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

    return loss / target_seq_out.shape[1]
```

To implement early stopping in this case, is it the same process to use `callback` etc., or is the process different? An example for this case is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any updates in the meantime?